# Is there fully-automatic fill-paragraph-mode for code comments?

Tags: hooks, fill-paragraph, comment

I'm looking for a minor mode to keep paragraphs filled at all times while typing (similar to what [`aggressive-indent-mode`](https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/aggressive-indent-mode) does for indentation). It also needs to be smart enough to only fill comments (and maybe strings depending on the language).

Some things that I've tried are:

- `auto-fill-mode` automatically fills while you are typing new paragraphs but doesn't refill when you edit paragraphs.
- `refill-mode` does constantly refill paragraphs but it tries to wrap code into paragraphs as well as comments.
- I tried adding `fill-paragraph` to the `after-change-functions` hook but it screws up undo and plenty of other things (this is probably all fixable but would take some effort).

Any better ideas?

Comment: Aside: chapter 7 of [Glickstein's *Writing GNU Emacs Extensions*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565922617.do) walks through how you might implement the functionality you're after.  Might be a great opportunity to learn/practice with elisp.

Comment: I'm looking the auto-fill-paragraph(with auto-fill enabled) in `org-mode`, but you may try [rebox2](https://github.com/lewang/rebox2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up with a minimal way of implementing this functionality: just bind space bar to also call `(fill-paragraph)`!

```
(defun fill-then-insert-space ()
  (interactive)
  (fill-paragraph)
  (insert " "))
(global-set-key (kbd "SPC") #'fill-then-insert-space)
```

There are a couple of caveat's that I've stumbled across so far:

1. `elisp-mode` (possibly others) does some fancy code filling when you call `fill-paragraph`, this may or may not be what you want. Can probably be fixed with by testing if point is in a comment or docstring but I'm not sure how to do that.
2. You sometimes can't easily enter multiple spaces (because the `fill-paragraph` kills any trailing spaces). Since the space-bar now acts like `just-one-space` it's probably ok to replace that binding with `(insert " ")`.

I made a minor-mode containing this functionality, it's available on [github](https://github.com/davidshepherd7/aggressive-fill-paragraph-mode) or in the melpa package `aggressive-fill-paragraph`.

Comment: I find it ironic that `aggressive-fill-paragraph` is far less aggressive than `refill-mode`, which is aggressive up to being pretty useless *(as you can't even quote someone with `> ` without refill-mode rearranging stuff: even if you use regexps for replacement)*.

Answer (score 1):

If you like how refill-mode behaves (I don't :p) but not *when* it behaves, it should be relatively easy to fix by inhibiting it whenever you're not in the right conditions

For example

```
(defvar plop/refill-enabler-function nil)

(defun plop/region-in-comment (beg end)
  ;; should really be comment-only-p, but that seems really broken for me
  (not
   (loop for c from beg to end
      if (not (eq 'font-lock-comment-face (get-char-property c 'face)))
      return t)))

(defun plop/refill-after-change-function (beg end len)
  (unless undo-in-progress
    (when (and plop/refill-enabler-function
               (funcall plop/refill-enabler-function beg end))
      (setq refill-doit end))))

(defun plop/install-refill-hack ()
  (if refill-mode
      (progn
        (add-hook 'after-change-functions 'plop/refill-after-change-function nil t)
        (remove-hook 'after-change-functions 'refill-after-change-function t))
    (progn
      (remove-hook 'after-change-functions 'plop/refill-after-change-function t))))

(defun plop/refill-hook ()
  (set (make-local-variable 'plop/refill-enabler-function)
       #'plop/region-in-comment)
  (add-hook 'refill-mode-hook 'plop/install-refill-hack t t)
  (refill-mode))

(add-hook 'some-hook 'plop/refill-hook)
```

Basically it removes the function that triggers the refill from `after-change-functions` and replaces it with one that will in addition check that we're in a comment before doing exactly the same thing.

Comment: Looks like a good start, but still not quite right: if a refill is triggered while editing a comment, it refills the whole paragraph, including the surrounding code. This may be the fault of the surrounding mode for not defining paragraph limits properly, but I doubt it: I tried in Emacs Lisp mode, which I presume does things by the book.

Comment: well, that's why I said I don't like `refill-mode` :) The problem is that `refill-mode` uses `fill-region` instead of `fill-paragraph`, thus losing the ability to honor `fill-paragraph-function` and making things potentially messy